# elemMatch equivalent in postgres

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, loopback

In my loopback application connected to mongoDB, i am using elemMatch to find the list of records.
What is the equivalent command/any approach when connected with postgres, to find the list of records present in JSONB array.
Am able to execute the following query in postgres prompt and able to get the output.
select * from table_name 'Array structure' @> '[{"'fieldName'":"VALUE"}]';
Let me know, how can i pass the above mentioned query in loopback.